# Get one or more string which starts and ends with into array

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to loop and get all string starts with `{` and ends with `}` into an array? For example:

```
Hi {recipient}, calling from {sender}. Your {item} has arrived.
```

Comment: Use a single regular expression. If you require specific help with this, please show what you've tried so we can help you debug it.

Comment: go ahead and use a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Comment: The duplicate uses square brackets, but the implementation is identical.

Comment: thanks everyone. will check out the references